# How can I make a method stall for a fixed amount of time?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, timer

I have an app that calls a sometimes-fast, sometimes-slow method. I know an upper bound for how long it will take (2 seconds). I'd like to set a timer to start when the method is called, run the code, but then not produce the output until 2 seconds has passed, no matter how long it actually takes. That way the user perceives the action as always taking the same amount of time. How can I implement this?

What I would like is something along the lines of this:

```
-(IBAction)doStuff {

  // START A TIMER, LOOK BUSY
  [activityIndicator startAnimating];

  ... real work happens here ...
  ... NSString *coolString gets assigned ...

  // WHEN TIMER == 2 SECONDS, REVEAL COOLNESS
  [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
  [textField setText:coolString];

}
```

Comment: Would sleep(unsigned seconds) work?

Comment: @anon: Using `sleep` is usually the wrong idea in Cocoa.

Comment: @PengOne: It is a C function. All it does is pause execution of the thread in which it's invoked for a given number of seconds.

Comment: I don't know why but I just had to upvote because the first `// comment` in your code coaxed a giggle out of me. And then I feel bad as I can't upvote again for the second one.

Comment: The big problem here is that the original (presumably main) thread is blocked (user can't do anything) while the "real work" is happening. This is also why you don't want to use `sleep`. Delaying execution is the easy part. @Bolt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to delay an action in Cocoa. The easiest may be to use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. This method sets up a timer for you and calls the specified method when the time comes. It's an `NSObject` method, so your objects all get it for free.

The tricky part here is that the first method will block the main thread, so you need get it onto a background thread, and then get back to the main thread in order to update the UI. Here's a stab at it:

```
// Put the method which will take a while onto another thread
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doWorkForUnknownTime)
                       withObject:nil];
// Delay the display for exactly two seconds, on the main thread
[self performSelector:@selector(displayResults)
           withObject:nil
           afterDelay:2.0];
```

---

```
- (void)doWorkForUnknownTime {

   // results is an ivar
   results = ...; // Perform calculations
}
```

---

```
- (void)displayResults {
    if( !results ){
        // Make sure that we really got results
        [self performSelector:@selector(displayResults:)
                   withObject:nil
                   afterDelay:0.5];
        return;
    }

    // Do the display!
}
```

The only other thing I can think of is to store the time that the "work" method is called in an `NSDate`, and check how long it took when you get the results. If it isn't two seconds yet, sleep the background thread, then call back to the main thread when you're done.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doWorkForUnknownTime:)
                       withObject:[NSDate date]];
```

---

```
- (void)doWorkForUnknownTime:(NSDate *)startTime {

   // All threads must have an autorelease pool in place for Cocoa.
   @autoreleasepool{
       // This will take some time
       NSString * results = ...; // Perform calculations

       NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];
       if( elapsedTime < 2.0 ){
           // Okay to do this to wait since we're on a background thread, 
           // although not ideal; sleeping threads are kind of wasteful.
           // Try not to do this a lot.
           sleep(2.0 - elapsedTime);
       }

       // Don't forget to retain results on the main thread!
       [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayResults:)
                              withObject:results
                           waitUntilDone:YES];
//     [results release];    // if necessary
    }
}
```

Comment: It will take a bit of time to pull my method apart to fit in this framework, but the idea looks good and I bet it works.

Comment: No, the method takes about 50 lines all together. The relevant info it there, though. Also, it wasn't so hard to split it. This works; thanks!

Comment: @PengOne: Okay, glad I could help! Hey, you just put me over 5k! Thanks!

Comment: Me, too! I spent a long time (> 2 seconds) getting no where on this :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myfunc) withObject: afterDelay:];
```

should help.

Comment: I'm not seeing the `afterDelay` option in the documentation. What input type does it take?

Comment: Do you have arguments in your selector? If so, use @selector(myfunc:)

Comment: Or you can use : timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(myfunc) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

Comment: I just wrote the same(the one which I suggested first) in my code. It is working fine.

Comment: @Nitish: this means that my method only begins after 2 seconds. I want start to finish to be exactly 2 seconds.

Comment: That really depends on what you are doing in your selector. If you are working with data like from web service or database, it may take time depending on certain factors I guess you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)doStuff {

  // START A TIMER, LOOK BUSY
  [activityIndicator startAnimating];

  ... real work happens here ...
  ... NSString *coolString gets assigned ...

  // WHEN TIMER == 2 SECONDS, REVEAL COOLNESS
[self performSelector:@selector(revealCoolnessWithString:) withObject:coolString afterDelay:2];

}

- (void)revealCoolnessWithString:(NSString *)coolString
{
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
[textField setText:coolString];
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Helpful, but this doesn't ensure that the time between the method being triggered and the result being displayed is 2 seconds. It does the method, takes some amount of time, then waits 2 seconds.